# Perform Visual Studio Data Compare automatically prior to running MSTest tests

Tags: mstest, data-comparison

I need to perform a data compare operation to refresh a dev database froma  sample data database prior to running integration tests using the VS test harness. Anyone know a way to automatically configure this?

Answer (score 1):

You need the MSBUILD Schema and Data Compare Tasks

from [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vstsdb/thread/eb9534e9-e537-4ecd-9f50-aaf0b57e5470)

```
MSBuild /t:SqlDataCompareTask 
   /p:SourceConnectionString=”ValidConnectionString1” 
   /p:SourceDatabaseName=”DatabaseName1”
   /P:TargetConnectionString=”ValidConnectionString2” 
   /p:TargetDatabaseName=”DatabaseName2”  
   /p:OutputPath=”FullPathForDataCompareReults”
   /p:OutputFilename=”FilenameForDataCompareResults”
```

Comment: MSBuild asks for a .proj file when you run this.. Any idea why?

Comment: Yes this is a command line execution of MSBUILD. You need to specify the msbuild project : `MSBuild.exe [Switches] [ProjectFile]`